# Can I duplicate a frame of an APNG animated image and have no noticeable increase in the file size?

Tags: frame, apng

I have an APNG animation with several frames, and it happens that some frames are exactly the same. Each of those frames are carrying its own image data in the file, where they could be just reusing the image data of a prior frame that is equal and save some space.

Any APNG expert know if in the APNG specification have a way of reusing the same image data for multiple frames?

Answer (score 1):

If the duplicate frames have no other different frames between them, you can eliminate all but one and reset the frame duration for the remaining one.  If there are different frames between them, then no.  APNG doesn't have a capability of reusing images.